# Get a parent class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, collections, closest

I want to get the ancetor of the `li` that have `active` class to target his son (the button) class an make a collapse by `area-expanded= true` in it.
This is the html:

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <button class="nav-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse-2" aria-controls="nav-collapse-2" aria-expanded="true">Typographies</button>

 <div class="nav-collapse collapse show" id="nav-collapse-2" style="">
  <div class="nav-collapse-inner">
   <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li class="nav-submenu-item">
          <a class="nav-submenu-link active" href="sg-typo-familles.html">Les familles</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-submenu-item">
         <a class="nav-submenu-link" href="sg-typo-hierarchisation.html">Hiérarchisation</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
```

this is some js :

```
var get_url = function (){
    $(".navbar-nav--left .nav-link, .nav-submenu .nav-submenu-link").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.attr('href') == window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)){
            // var regex = /\/\/.*\/(.*)\//g;
            // var match = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            // console.log("eeeeeee : ",match )
            $this.addClass('active');
            // var collapsed = $(".nav-item *");

            collapsed = $(this).closest(".nav-item")[0];

        }
    });
};
```

I'm stuck in this piece of code :(

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If you're using bootstrap, the right way to toggle a collapse event should look like [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#collapseshow)

Comment: Bit confusing as it looks like you've provided some code that sets the active class, but not the code that you've asked for: `$(".active").closest(".nav-item").find("button.nav-link")`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand well your question, but in order to get the parentElement of an element with a class `.active` here is how:

```
let myElement = document.getElementByClassName("active")[0];
let brotherButton = myElement.parentNode.querySelectorAll("a")[0];
```

Above we've got myElement which has the class `.active`, then thru his parent we selected his brother anchor tag.
Hope this help.